# How to get the current stage running in an Azure DevOps pipeline build?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-devops-rest-api

Using this endpoint only shows overall pipeline run status:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs/{runId}
```

Using this endpoint can check stage status, but not of a specific run:

```
https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/build/status/{definition}?stageName=[stage]
```

I want to get the current stage running in a pipeline build in Azure DevOps. So for example, there are multiple runs ongoing, I want to be able to get which stage each run is in.

Comment: James Z did you find any way to do it?

Answer (score 3):

Found a way using the timeline endpoint:
https://dev.azure.com/$ORGANIZATION/$PROJECT/_apis/build/builds/$BUILDID/timeline?api-version=6.0

Then parsing the records array, to get the stages and their current state.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Myke I wasn't able to use such restAPI. Possible that it is outdated. Can you show how to use it?

Comment: `curl -u ":$PAT" "https://dev.azure.com/$ORG/$PROJECT/_apis/build/builds/$BUILD_ID/timeline\?api-version\=6.0"`

or you can ommit the api-version:

`curl -u ":$PAT" "https://dev.azure.com/$ORG/$PROJECT/_apis/build/builds/$BUILD_ID/timeline"`

This endpoint still works. Just make sure you have the correct values for org, project, build_id, and your PAT has read access to builds.

Answer (score 1):

Using the sample at https://devblogs.microsoft.com/premier-developer/how-to-retrieve-all-work-items-associated-with-a-release-pipeline-using-azure-devops-api/
I was able to check if the production stage was run (to generate release notes) using:

```
var timeline = buildClient.GetBuildTimelineAsync(project: projectName, buildId: buildItem.Id).Result;

var prodTimeline = timeline.Records.Where(r => r.RecordType == "Stage" && r.Name == "Deploy to prd" && r.Result == TaskResult.Succeeded).FirstOrDefault();
```